# Forwarded email replay with phpmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, replay, return-path

Normally when we send a reply email we just add "Re:" in email subject but when a email come from any other forwarded email then how can I reply to this email?

Example:

> an email is sent from *john@example.com*, forwarded from *john2@example.com*, and received at email address *received@example.com*.
>   Now when I send a reply from *received@example.com* to the sender *john@example.com* what should I do?

I tried using "Re:" in subject but it not act as reply email.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether an email is treated as a reply is *not* dependent on the subject line. A message that is a reply will have an `In-Reply-To` and/or `References` headers containing the message id(s) of the messages it is a reply to or forward of. This is defined in [RFC5322 section 3.6.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.6.4). When replying to a message, you need to extract the message ID from the original message and insert it in the `references` header, preserving any existing entries in there. You can set this in PHPMailer using the [`addCustomHeader()`](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.html#method_addCustomHeader) method.

As far as I'm aware, there is no internal distinction between a reply and a forward - both will add to the references header - the only usual difference is who they are sent to, and often by adding a prefix to the subject line (often `re:` or `fw:`, but it varies between languages), but note that this is purely cosmetic and informational - it does not alter the behaviour of the message nor how it is linked to other messages.